# Top parts from Activity got hidden when soft keyboard shown

Tags: android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

I have an Activity contains TextView ----> ListView ------> TextField (from top to bottom). My problem when the soft keyboard is shown for TextField, The top parts from the activity scroll up and hidden. I added this line on my manifest but didn't solve the problem

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

I want to make the soft keyboard is always shown and in the same time the all parts of my activity are visible, there is no problem to resize the ListView to make free space for the soft keyboard, but how to make that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What is you container: LinearLayout (vertical) or RelativeLayout ?

For LinearLayout try the following lines for ListView:

```
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
```

This will tell ListView to use all available height.

For a RelativeLayout

```
   android:layout_allignTop="@+id/topTextId"
   android:layout_allignBottom="@+id/bottomTextId"
```

will do the same trick.

Comment: unfortunately didn't work  android:layout_height="0dp" cases white screen, Thanks